# How can I make a tweak that has multiple options to choose from with THEOS

Tags: tweak, theos

So I was thinking of making a tweak for my iOS device and I wanted to make a settings patcher that had a few options for the user to choose from.

Example: Changing the color of the screen flash. If I wanted to have a range of colors for the user to choose how would I make the tweak.xm look?

```
%hook SBScreenFlash

- (void)flashColor:(id) {
//What would go here so that multiple options would show?
}

%end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make preferences for your tweak, you should think about making a PreferenceBundle using Theos (it's one of the built-in templates).

You can find documentation about it on [iphonedevwiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceBundles). The PreferenceBundle will then write the user's settings to a file named `com.yourname.yourprefbundle.plist` located in `/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/`

Your tweak will have to read in this plist and do something accordingly